# Hibernate: Save multiple association issue

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities with relations.

```
public class Site {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Page> pages;
}

public class Page {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Article> articles;

    @OneToMany
    private List<TopArticle> topArticles;
}

public class Article {
    @ManyToOne
    private Page page;
}

public class TopArticle {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PageId")
    private Page page;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ArticleId")
    private Article article;
}
```

Fields **page** and **arctile** in **TopArticle** have database restrictions - **NOT NULL**. (***Resctrictions are required***)

I have to save Site with all associations.

```
    Article article = new Article();
    TopArticle topArticle = new TopArticle();

    Page page = new Page();
    page.getArticles().add(article);
    page.getTopArticles().add(topArticle);

    Site site = new Site();
    site.getPages().add(page);

    siteDAO.save(site);
```

Sometimes it saves site.
But sometimes it throws an error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ArticleId', table '...TopArticle'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails
```

It seems that after **Page** is saved, it tries to save associations ***List articles*** and ***List topArticles***.
Perhaps, when ***List articles*** are saved before ***List topArticles*** it works.
In another way it fails.

**Questions:**

*Is an issue in saving properties order in JPA?*

*How can I enforce Hibernate to save ***articles*** before ***topArticles***?*

*Is there any other solutions?*

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

With a bi-directional relationship it is your responsibility to ensure both sides are set correctly on the in-memory model otherwise you will get the error you are seeing.

So you need to call:

`article.setPage(page);`

And ideally you should encapsulate the operation so the in-memory model is always consistent:

```
public class Page{

    public List<Article> getArticles(){
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(articles); //force through add method
    }

    public void addArticle(Article article){
        articles.add(article);
        article.setPage(this);
    }
}
```